# I want to search a directory for multiple files using PHP and start a download them over HTTP

Tags: php, file, directory, transfer

Just to start, I'm a PHP noob.

I have an Apache server which hosts my files. I have a device which can only point to one PHP file. What I need it to do is have my PHP file read in the name of the file I want to download, and point it towards the directory it is stored. Currently, I have it pointing to one file, but I need it to be able to point to multiple. Is this possible in PHP?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php 
$file_name = 'file.img';
$size = filesize($file_name);
$file_url = 'http://192.168.0.5/' . $file_name;
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
readfile($file_url);?>
```

Edit:
The commands I want to input in order to download the file are close enough to as follows:

```
cmd=download+-a+$$.img+altimage
cmd=download+-a+$$.conf+altconfig
```

and the download directory is the .php file. I am open to other suggestions in how to do this.

Edit2:
Here's what an exact sample URL is:

```
 myserver.com/cgi-bin/va/cmd?hdl+fullconfig.ini+altconfig
```

the hdl is a predefined function which points to the download directory, in order to download the file from the server, so the layout of what you mean isn't exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have trouble understanding what exactly you're trying to do, but I guess that you want a user to be able to download multiple files. If that is correct, here is one way to achieve this:

You can let PHP create a ZIP archive using the [ZIP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php). For it to work, you have to load the extension php_zip.dll inside your php.ini.

```
$ZIP = new ZipArchive();

// Use the current time as the filename to prevent two users to use the same file
$ZIPName = microtime().".zip";

// Create a new ZIP file
$ZIP->open($ZIPName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

// Loop through all files - $Files needs to be an array with the names of the files you want to add, including the paths
// basename() will prevent the creation of folders inside the ZIP
foreach ($Files as $File) {
    $ZIP->addFile($File, basename($File));
}

// Close the archive
$ZIP->close();

// Send the archive to the browser
readfile($ZIPName);
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this isn't really what I am looking to do. For example, I want to download sample_file1 and sample_file2, specifying the file names in my command/address bar. I want my PHP file to be able to send the file from the directory, with appropriate headers etc. The code which I posted above is just a forced download for 'file.img', but I want it to be able to process other names (taking the command/address bar as its input). Hopefully this makes more sense!

Comment: Is it only that you want to specify the to-be-downloaded file in the URL like myscript.php?file=sample_file1 and that sends you sample_file1? Then you could read the URL parameter by using $_GET["file"]. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. I'll play around with it and see if I can get it to wrok. Sorry if my question seems stupid, I'm very new to PHP! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, but I fear I can't help you with this. I simply don't get what you're up to. I hope someone else or even you comes up with a solution.